# Why is there more than 1 solution that requires 20 moves in rubic cube solving?

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, rubiks-cube

Imagine a group generated by this 3 elements

1, x, y

Say there is no relationship whatsoever between x and y and say both are cyclic of order 2. We know that the group must have at most 4 elements right?

I mean, 1, x, y, xy.

Am I correct here? So there is only 1 element "farthest" from identity, namely, xy.

I must be a bit wrong here because yx may not be an inverse of xy, but I think I am on to something.

So it seems that the fartheest element on a finite group should only be 1 at most.

Am I wrong?

Actually, if a group has generators with limited cycles, is there a way to measure the number of all distinct elements in the group? Why is it so difficult to proof that the God's number for rubic is 20?

I mean all rubic position, assuming that the center never moves, can be generated with 6 elements with 4 cycle each right. So is there a formula that can compute the number of positions that can be solved in 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ... steps?

Comment: There are a lot of groups. Any intuition based on one (tiny) example is likely to be wrong.

Comment: Also, a group with two generators, each of finite order, can be infinite.

Comment: really? Where can I see that?

Comment: And yet numbers of rubic position is finite.

Comment: [Free group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group) is infinite. Wait, you wanted the generators to be of finite order? Try [free product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product) $\mathbb Z_2\star\mathbb Z_2$. Rubik's group is indeed finite, but pretty large.

Comment: The word you are looking for, Jim, is Rubik. A group with finitely many generators, each of finite order, **can** be infinite. Not *must*; **can**. I've given an example at the other question you asked.

Comment: I hope this article will be  helpful to you. There is another one in the same magazine by the same author you may also want to check.
https://www.scientificamerican.com/video/math-puts-a-new-twist-on-solving-a-rubik-s-cube-with-the-fewest-moves/

Comment: In your example, your group would have infinitely many elements.  Since the elements are not given to be commutative, $xyx\not=x^2y=y$.  Therefore, there are elements $1$, $x$, $y$, $xy$, $xyx$, $yx$, $xyxy$, $\cdots$

Comment: Consider the matrices $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 &0 \end{bmatrix}$ and  $B=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ \frac{1}{2} &0 \end{bmatrix}$. Then you can check that $A^2=B^2=I_2$ but $AB$ has infinite order.

Comment: Note that the group of Rubik's cube is not commutative (the order in which you do moves matters).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the non-abelian group of order $21$ generated by $a$ and $b$ as follows:

$G=\langle a,b | a^3,b^3,(ab)^3,ab^{-1}ab^{-1}a^{-1}b\rangle$

Allowing $a$, $a^{-1}$, $b$, $b^{-1}$ to be our "moves" like on a Rubik's cube we obtain the following.

$0$ moves: Identity

$1$ move: $a$, $a^{-1}$, $b$, $b^{-1}$

$2$ moves: $ab$, $ab^{-1}$, $a^{-1}b$, $a^{-1}b^{-1}$, $ba$, $ba^{-1}$, $b^{-1}a$, $b^{-1}a^{-1}$

$3$ moves: $aba$, $aba^{-1}$, $ab^{-1}a$, $ab^{-1}a^{-1}$, $a^{-1}ba^{-1}$, $a^{-1}b^{-1}a$, $bab$, $ba^{-1}b$

This accounts for all $21$ elements, and we see that $8$ elements require $3$ moves to reach, and there is no one farthest element.

To assist in the calculation I drew on a Cayley diagram of this group from http://www.weddslist.com/rmdb/g.php?m=21.1

[image: f21 cayley]